# Removing double quotes from a csv file

Tags: perl, sed, tr

I want to remove all double quotes from my csv file, and am struggling to get tr, sed, or perl to work for me and output to file:

`perl -e 's/\"//g;" input.csv > output.csv`
gives no output to screen or file, with output.csv not created

`sed 's/\"//g' input.csv > output.csv`
prints output to the screen, and then gives errors "can't read >: No such file or directory" "can't read output.csv: No such file or directory"

`cat input.csv | tr -d '\"' > output.csv`
gives error "tr: extra operand '>'", then error "write error: No space left on device"

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this (untested):

```
tr -d "\"" < input > output
```

Comment: Windows doesn't like single quotes - I'll revise my answer.

Comment: Excellent - this does it.

Comment: I think perl, awk, sed and tr all have to use double quotes in Windows.

Comment: It's more like the Windows Command Prompt requires double quotes, and doesn't make exceptions for Perl, awk, sed, tr, or even the great Dijkstra.

Answer (score 5):

To get your perl version to work, you just need the `-p` option to indicate printing to the screen:

```
perl -pe 's/"//g' input.csv > output.csv
```

Or if you're on windows, do the following:

```
perl -pe "s/\x22//g" input.csv > output.csv
```

Also, instead of blindly removing double quotes from a csv, I'd recommend using an actual csv parser to selectively remove double quotes only from those fields where it isn't needed.  The following script could do that:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Text::CSV;

my $csv = Text::CSV->new ( { binary => 1, eol => "\n" } )
                or die "Cannot use CSV: ".Text::CSV->error_diag();

if (@ARGV != 1) {
    print "usage: $0 [csvfile]\n";
    exit;
}

while (<>) {
    $csv->parse($_);
    $csv->combine( $csv->fields() );
    print $csv->string();
}
```

Comment: Still not working, it's saying "Can't do inplace edit: > is not a regular file" and "Can't open output.csv: No such file or directory"

I interpret these as perl trying to read ">" and "output.csv" as files to apply the command to...

Comment: Wrote a new 1-liner for windows.

Comment: +1 (because that's all anyone's allowed to upvote) for suggesting Text::CSV.  Let the proper tool do the proper tool's job.

Comment: Tried to deal with structured data in an unstructured way is always painful.